# Doctrine 2 - Referencing a specific associated collection item

Tags: doctrine-orm

In my current model I have 2 entities: `Student` and `StudentOrdersHistory`. We're using a history table to record all the orders from the student.

However, we particularly need to work with the latest order history.  At first, I used some circular reference like the following:

```
StudentOrderHistory.student_id  --> Student

Student.latest_order  --> StudentOrderHistory
```

The reason for this is that we expect the relation to have hundreds of rows (student here is just an example to make it simple to ask what I need), but since we mostly need to work with the last one, we figured it's pointless loading all of them and then doing some `$student->orders->last()`, since it'd have to load all the records.

Needless to say, this implementation brought a pain when deleting a `Student`, as the circular reference won't let me do it without first having to delete the `Student.latest_order` reference.

Is there anyway I can load into a `Student` property (like `Student::$latestOrder`) only the latests one using DQL?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you might not be able to do it directly through the Student object. Sacrificing this convenience should get your the performance improvement you want, and in fact [doctrine best practices](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/best-practices.html#constrain-relationships-as-much-as-possible) suggest constraining relationships as much as possible.

I haven't tested this code, but you probably know how to get it working. I'd add a method to the OrderRepository, like

```
public function getLatestForStudent(Student $student)
{
    $this->findOneBy(['student' => $student], ['created']);
}
```